# SVG to PNG without width Attribute

Tags: javascript, svg, png

Oh hi. I have an SVG that i'm converting into a png and uploading to the server. Everything works as long as I explicitly give a width and height value in the SVG tag. I'm using viewBox=" " to give the SVG an aspect ratio, without the width and height attribute the svg scales nicely into the browser window. Therefore, I don't want to include width and height in the tag.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```js
var svg = document.querySelector( "svg" );
var svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString( svg );
var nzs ="";
var canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );
canvas.width = $('#mainSVG').width();// I tried giving the canvas a size, but it doesn't help 
canvas.height = $('#mainSVG').height();
console.log(canvas.width +" " + canvas.height);
var ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
var img = document.createElement( "img" );
img.setAttribute( "src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa( svgData ) );
img.onload = function() {
 ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0);
// ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0, $('#mainSVG').width(), $('#mainSVG').height() ); // I tried setting the image size in this line but it didn't work either.
 nzs= canvas.toDataURL( "image/png" ); 
 $.ajax({
   url:"hidden.php",
   data:{base64: nzs},
   type:"post",
   complete:function(){
  console.log("Ready");
   }
 });
 };
```

```html
<svg id="mainSVG" clasxmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2800 1600">
<!-- <svg id="mainSVG" clasxmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2800 1600" width="800" height="1000"> If i use this tag everything works --!>
```

How can I insert a dynamically created width and height into the SVG tag? I thought of manipulating the svgData string to include the width and height attribute, but that can't be the easiest way of doing it.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var svg = document.querySelector( "svg" ).cloneNode(true); 
svg.setAttribute("width", "whatever");
svg.setAttribute("height", "something else");
```

then continue as you were. [cloneNode creates a deep copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) and you can then just set attributes in your copy as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done but it's a it cumbersome.

First you have to get the outerHTML of your svg element

```
var mySvg = document.getElementById("mySvg").outerHTML;
```

This will return something like

```
<svg id="mySvg" viewBox="0 0 2800 1600"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"></circle> </svg>
```

Now we need to 'inject' the width and height attributes. Unfortunately Javascript's String object doesn't offer a built-in way to insert text at a specific position - so we need to use our own function to do this.

```
String.prototype.splice = function(index, charsToRemove, str) {
  return this.slice(0, index) + str + this.slice(index + Math.abs(charsToRemove));
};

var width = 200;
var height = 300;

mySvg = mySvg.splice(mySvg.indexOf("svg") + 3, 0, ' width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '"');
```

This is what it will look like afterwards

```
<svg width="200" height="300" id="mySvg" viewBox="0 0 2800 1600">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

Finally let's get rid of the **viewBox** attribute. To do this we need to get the start index of it inside mySvg and from there get the indexes for the first **"** and the last **"**. With the start- and endindex we can utilize the splice() method once more.

```
var startIndex = mySvg.indexOf("viewBox");
var endIndex = startIndex;
var occurences = 0;
do {
  if (mySvg.charAt(endIndex) == '"') {
    occurences++;
  }
  endIndex++;
}
while (occurences < 2);

mySvg = mySvg.splice(startIndex,endIndex-startIndex,'');
```

and change the outerHTML of the svg element

```
document.getElementById("mySvg").outerHTML = mySvg;
```

Here's the complete example:

```js
String.prototype.splice = function(index, charsToRemove, str) {
  return this.slice(0, index) + str + this.slice(index + Math.abs(charsToRemove));
};

function modify(width, height) {
  var mySvg = document.getElementById("mySvg").outerHTML;

  mySvg = mySvg.splice(mySvg.indexOf("svg") + 3, 0, ' width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '"');

  var startIndex = mySvg.indexOf("viewBox");
  var endIndex = startIndex;
  var occurences = 0;
  do {
    if (mySvg.charAt(endIndex) == '"') {
      occurences++;
    }
    endIndex++;
  }
  while (occurences < 2);

  mySvg = mySvg.splice(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex, '');
  document.getElementById("mySvg").outerHTML = mySvg;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="modify(400,300)">modify</button>
<svg id="mySvg" viewBox="0 0 2800 1600">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```